# Is possible getdata() with initials 0?

Tags: php

I would like the date/time that is saved in the database to have leading zeros in the days/hours/minutes/seconds...

```
$mydate = getdate();
        $time= 'Update: ' . $mydate[mday].'/'.$mydate[mon].'/'.$mydate[year].' - '. $mydate[hours].':'.$mydate[minutes].':'.$mydate[seconds];
```

If I save this, I get something like this: Update: 8/22/2023 - 4:41:1, and I want the leading zeros

How can I get getdate() to catch my leading zeros in the code snippet I've shared?

Comment: Things like leading zeros are considered formatting which is usually only done when you need to display data. It is recommended to instead store as a true date/time in the DB to get the advantages when querying, sorting, etc. However, if you really want to, you can just store it as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the `DateTime` object:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

```
$myDate = new \DateTime();
$time = 'Update: ' . $myDate->format('d') . '/' . $myDate->format('m') . '/' . $myDate->format('Y') .' - '. $myDate->format('H') . ':' . $myDate->format('i') . ':' . $myDate->format('s');
```

When instantiating the `DateTime` object you also get the actual time.

If you absolutly want to use the `getdate()` function you can set the date in the the `DateTime` object by setting a timestamp.

```
$actualDate = getdate();
$myDate = new \DateTime();
$myDate->setTimestamp($actualDate[0]);
$time = 'Update: ' . $myDate->format('d') . '/' . $myDate->format('m') . '/' . $myDate->format('Y') .' - '. $myDate->format('H') . ':' . $myDate->format('i') . ':' . $myDate->format('s');
```

But as Chris Haas already mentioned in the comments above, it is not recommended to save date data as string in the database. Better way is to save the timestamp and format it when used for output.

Comment: "it is not recommended to save date data as string in the database. " Why? And thanks for ur help :)

Comment: Because you cant calculate dates in string format. I.e. you want to fetch all entries before an specific date. This is not possible, with dates in string format.